# Running Animation From Code Behind

Tags: c#, .net, animation, storyboard, windows-phone

i have the storyboard than i wanted to apply on a button from code behind.
my storyboard is defined in view.cs class like this..

```
private const string ANIMATION_FOCUSREGIONTEXT =
@"<Storyboard xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"">
        <DoubleAnimation Duration=""0:0:0.25"" To=""0"" RepeatBehavior=""Forever"" Storyboard.TargetProperty=""(UIElement.Opacity)"">
            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                <ExponentialEase EasingMode=""EaseIn"" Exponent=""3"" />
            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
        </DoubleAnimation>
    </Storyboard>";

    private Storyboard _focusregionStoryborad = XamlReader.Load(ANIMATION_FOCUSREGIONTEXT) as Storyboard;
```

when i tried this..

```
 Button asd = new Button();
            asd.Width = 100;
            asd.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            asd.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);

            videoRectangle.Children.Add(asd);

 Storyboard.SetTargetName(_focusregionStoryborad, "asd");
            _focusregionStoryborad.Completed += _focusregionStoryborad_Completed;
           _focusregionStoryborad.Begin();  // error
```

the Exception **System.InvalidOperationException** come on this line

```
_focusregionStoryborad.Begin();
```

am i missing something ..any help is appreciated..

Comment: Why don't you define the storyboard in XAML and then call it from the Resource?

Comment: i am just trying this option..i am curious why it is not playing